# Python Google App Engine - Get location

Tags: python, google-app-engine, location

I'm trying to get the closest coordinates of a user and I have used location by public IP address but it doesn't have enough accuracy.

Is there a way to get the users location with `Google App Engine` like this one http://www.gps-coordinates.net/where-am-i ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our use case, we just needed city of the user. The request header of app engine gives the latitude longitude, city and country of the user.

```
self.request.headers['X-Appengine-Citylatlong']
self.request.headers['X-Appengine-City']
```

This gives almost 90% accuracy in our case.

Comment: Thank you very much, I haven't thought that because I'm in development environment but if I deploy my application it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [maxmind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/home) ? I used maxmind with google appengine. It's pretty good and I hope it suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I will test it.